# Could not install tweepy, a python library in Ubuntu 16.04 in a remote host allocated by LONI using pip and easy_install

Tags: python, twitter, pip, installation, tweepy

Whenever I try to install tweepy, a python library inside a remote host, it fails, although I have pip and python of appropriate version installed. My python version is anaconda 2.7.13 and pip version is 9.0.1. Thanks in advance!

So, I have tried the following commands below and none of them worked.

```
    pip install tweepy

    pip install --user tweepy
```

It gives the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
    File "/usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 239, in main
ensure_easy_pth()
    File "/usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 217, in 
    ensure_easy_pth
    with open(path, 'w') as fo:
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth'
```

When I try to use easy_install:

```
   easy_install tweepy
```

It gives the error:

```
   error: can't create or remove files in install directory
   The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the installation directory:
   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-40557.write-test'
   The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or the distutils default setting) was:
    /usr/local/packages/python/2.7.10-anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
    Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
    For information on other options, you may wish to consult the 
    documentation at: 
    https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html
    Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Comment: try with `sudo`?

Comment: I can't use sudo because I am in a remote host. It does work outside of it.

Comment: Does `pip install --user tweepy` produce the same error? Can you try `virtualenv`?

Comment: Yup, the same error mentioned above.

Comment: And I also tried to install virtualenv but since that is also done using pip, same error occurred. pip is not doing what it needs to.